# How to check if a specified user is admin on a local computer or not?

Tags: c, windows

I want to know, if a user is administrator on a PC or not? I found a code snippet, which does this, but i have a problem with it. The problem with this code is, that this function will return if the user, who started the process has admin rights or not. But i want to query if a specific user has administrator rights or not. Can i do this somehow? This is important because my application will run under SYSTEM account, so it will always return that the user is admin, but i want to know if the logged on user is admin or not?

Code snippet:

```
BOOL IsUserAdmin( VOID )
/*++ 
Routine Description: This routine returns TRUE if the caller's
process is a member of the Administrators local group. Caller is NOT
expected to be impersonating anyone and is expected to be able to
open its own process and process token. 
Arguments: None. 
Return Value: 
  TRUE - Caller has Administrators local group. 
  FALSE - Caller does not have Administrators local group. --
*/ 
{
BOOL b;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
PSID AdministratorsGroup; 

b = AllocateAndInitializeSid(
                                &NtAuthority,
                                2,
                                SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
                                DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                &AdministratorsGroup
                            ); 
if ( b ) 
{
    if ( !CheckTokenMembership( NULL, AdministratorsGroup, &b ) ) 
    {
        b = FALSE;
    } 
    FreeSid( AdministratorsGroup ); 
}

return ( b );
}
```

Comment: Which logged on user? There could be many. And don't use the SYSTEM account. This is 2011.

Comment: In my company there is one logged on user at a time :) Why not use System account? This is a bit complicated, but there is a schedule task which will call a .bat file, and run every application which is inside it. The scheduled task run's under SYSTEM account.

Comment: You aren't supposed to run under SYSTEM account. It's too powerful. Bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the following steps.

1. Decide which logged on user you want to pick on, there could be more than one. I would identify them using a process, e.g. the explorer process.
2. Call [`OpenProcessToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) passing the process handle. Make sure you specify `TOKEN_DUPLICATE`.
3. Call [`DuplicateToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446616%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get an impersonation token.
4. Call `CheckTokenMembership()` as before but passing the token rather than `NULL`.
5. Tidy up!

Answer (score 1):

1. Run your user interface within the logged-on user account.  This protects the privileged service against shatter attacks.
2. Use DCOM to forward requests from  the GUI to the privileged service.  Use impersonation within the privileged service to discover the rights of the user.

Comment: 3. Don't run the service privileged.

Comment: @David: Some level of privilege is often needed, although it probably shouldn't be "SYSTEM", depending on the details of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog article on MSDN:

[How To Determine Whether a Thread Is Running in User Context of Local Administrator Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff420334.aspx)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon, since links can break over time, invalidating the answer.  At the very least, you should summarize what the link explains, so if the link does break, some useful information is still available.